# Mounted devices are not shown in File manager folder tree items

Tags: permissions, file-manager, nemo

Good day everybody recently I've installed Arch on my computer and I'm still trying to figure it out why are the mounted devices (HDD) are missing from the Home folder tree in my File manager? To see it more clear what I mean:

[image: basic]

but when I run it with `sudo` I get this view:

[image: root]

I'm assuming I must be missing some *permissions* for this?

All extra devices are mounted to `/mnt` folder which in *properties* indicates `root` as the *owner*.

How can I make it look the same without running `sudo`?

*UPDATE*

```
cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# UUID=7b8195aa-4480-433e-b258-7b5607977dbb
/dev/sda1               /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 1

# UUID=dec7470a-c024-4f87-aa38-03d1d0bc214c
/dev/sda5               /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2

# UUID=e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2 LABEL=Movies
/dev/sdb1               /mnt/movies     ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2

# UUID=4eafe188-0b7d-4083-9ef2-c3370e881455 LABEL=Media
/dev/sdb2               /mnt/media      ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2

# UUID=bb278797-cdd3-4f28-acb8-809935e48bb9
/dev/sda6               none        swap        defaults    0 0

sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="7b8195aa-4480-433e-b258-7b5607977dbb" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3cde3cdd-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="dec7470a-c024-4f87-aa38-03d1d0bc214c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3cde3cdd-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="bb278797-cdd3-4f28-acb8-809935e48bb9" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="3cde3cdd-06"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Movies" UUID="e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0008db75-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Media" UUID="4eafe188-0b7d-4083-9ef2-c3370e881455" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0008db75-02"
```

*UPDATE 2*

```
cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# UUID=7b8195aa-4480-433e-b258-7b5607977dbb
/dev/sda1               /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 1

# UUID=dec7470a-c024-4f87-aa38-03d1d0bc214c
/dev/sda5               /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2

# UUID=e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2 LABEL=Movies
                    /mnt/movies     ext4        rw,user,auto,acl            0 2

# UUID=4eafe188-0b7d-4083-9ef2-c3370e881455 LABEL=Media
                    /mnt/media      ext4        rw,user,auto,acl            0 2

# UUID=bb278797-cdd3-4f28-acb8-809935e48bb9
/dev/sda6               none        swap        defaults    0 0


mount | grep sdb

/dev/sdb2 on /run/media/admin/Media type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/admin/Movies type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: You mount them over /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Yes they are mounted and present in */etc/fstab* as I said when I launch File Manager with root privileges I can see them mounted as on the screenshot above.

Comment: Then edit your question `cat /etc/fstab`  and with sudo or as root `blkid`

Comment: sorry for the hold up... the outputs added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! ok I'll contribute my answer to this thread maybe it will help somebody else with the same issue.

So there's a quick workaround to this but I'll try to reproduce my steps.

Firstly my *fstab* looked like this:

```
# UUID=e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2 LABEL=Movies
/dev/sdb1               /mnt/movies     ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2
```

But thanks to @Bahamut I managed to change it to this and mountable devices appeared on Home folder tree:

```
# UUID=e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2 LABEL=Movies
                    /mnt/movies     ext4        rw,user,auto,acl            0 2
```

After that I changed it again to:

```
# UUID=e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2 LABEL=Movies
                    /mnt/movies     ext4        uid=1000,gid=100,umask=0022,auto,nosuid,nodev,rw,relatime,data=ordered  0 2
```

Only for the security meassures you can read more on *fstab* [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) *Do note!* that `uid` and `gid` may differ in your system from example above.

But now I faced the issue every time I reboot the system it will ask for the *root* password which is kinda annoying but yes might be good for the security meassures.

I started to google for the workaround and found a solution to edit *sudoers* file to remove *sudo* when using with *mount* but that is highly not recommended for the security purpose so I skipped this workaround and not recommend it either.

So after I clicked on *partition icon* to mount it the pop up window appeared

[image: popup]

And at the left bottom corner I clicked *Details Action* which showed: ***org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system***

As I found out later it appears to be a *policy rule* but one can change it just run in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy
```

you can use *nano* as well or your fav. and in opened window search for the lines:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system">

    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

and change it to:

```
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

Save & close the file.

now `sudo reboot`

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

Does it work if you add `x-gvfs-show` to fstab? e.g

```
UUID=5a1615ca-cffd3124917a /mnt/storage ext4 rw,noatime,discard,x-gvfs-show 0 2
```

P.S you can also mount disks with `udisksctl` command, e.g `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2 -t ext4`, which will show normally in modern File Manager

Answer (score 1):

Change this Entries

```
# UUID=e2fc4ba5-3b2a-4dd8-9d35-eba0d1f83fc2 LABEL=Movies
/dev/sdb1               /mnt/movies     ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2
# UUID=4eafe188-0b7d-4083-9ef2-c3370e881455 LABEL=Media
/dev/sdb2               /mnt/media      ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered0 2
```

to

```
LABEL=Media  /mnt/media      ext4  rw,user,auto,acl   0 2     

LABEL=Movies /mnt/movies     ext4  rw,user,auto,acl   0 2
```

The Option `x-gvfs-show` is also a possibility as daisy wrotes, but     personal I don't like it. It is no good Idea to mount over /dev/device-nodes. Better is over UUID or LABEL. It identifies a special partition. And only for that partition the entry in /etc/fstab  effect.

Comment: ok it works now! removing */dev/sdb1* and *2* solved it... but still what is the issue if */dev/sdb* is listed in *fstab* file? And one more thing now I can see my devices in Home folder tree but when I click on it every time after reboot it asks for *root* password?

Comment: Again `cat /etc/fstab `  and `mount | grep sdb`

Comment: output added...